# Minimum age to reproduce

Tags: reproduction

How old does one (male and female human) have to be in order to reproduce
Im thinking that it's 13 for a boy and 3 for a girl, is that right?

Comment: What is your definition of reproduction?  Does it just involve a female getting pregnant, or does it involve carrying it to term.  It seems highly unlikely that a 3 year old could carry a fetus to term.

Comment: Cross-posted at [Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/16512/minimum-age-to-reproduce) and underresearched.- please delete one post and refine the other, most of all add some prior research and correct the 3 years for a girl's reproductive age. That's just plain nonsense.

Answer (score 7):

The youngest fathers recorded were 11 years old (see [wikipedia > 
List of youngest birth fathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_youngest_birth_fathers)).

The youngest mother recorded is [L. Medina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lina_Medina) was 5 years, 7 months and 21 days old when giving birth, which is rather astonishing! Of course, she gave birth by a caesarean section. She had an extremely early puberty; she appears to have had her period when she was 3 years old only. You might want to have a look at [wikipedia > List of youngest birth mothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_youngest_birth_mothers). According to [this article](http://motherhow.com/youngest-parents/), a mother (L. Gryshchenko) became a mother at 6 years old and gave birth "naturally" (not by cesarian section).

Comment: Not propably but definitly :). But  it is nice answer.

Comment: @L.Diago Not probably, not definitely, but definitely not - in its current shape the question is unfit for any site in the SE network. Whoever upvoted the question should re-think their motivations to do so -1. The answer is fine but removed my upvote as it's an answer on a question that should've been improved first, or put on hold altogether.

Comment: Dear ALiceD i was on your side. I didnt mean it on that way. :D Btw thank you, because i have never noticed that mistake.